# Date displays as float in CSV file

Tags: excel, csv

I am trying to save some data in csv file. Some of the date formats are changed to float after .

This is data:

```
results = [{'Event ID': 15, 'Time Start': '2022/05/04 17:75', 'Time End': '2022/05/04 18:00''}
{'Event ID': 15, 'Time Start': '2022/05/04 18:00', 'Time End': '2022/05/04 20:50'}
{'Event ID': 0, 'Time Start': '2022/05/06 16:50', 'Time End': '2022/05/06 17:00'}
{'Event ID': 4, 'Time Start': '2022/05/09 15:00', 'Time End': '2022/05/09 15:50'}
{'Event ID': 14, 'Time Start': '2022/06/13 07:75', 'Time End': '2022/06/13 08:00'}
{'Event ID': 4, 'Time Start': '2022/06/15 09:00', 'Time End': '2022/06/15 10:50'}
{'Event ID': 14, 'Time Start': '2022/06/16 02:75', 'Time End': '2022/06/16 03:00'}]
```

The code to save it as csv is as shown below

```
 csv_columns = ['Event ID', 'Time Start', 'Time End']
    csv_file = "ets_results.csv"
    try:
        with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in results: 
                print(data)
                writer.writerow(data)
    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")
```

The output of the csv file looks like this

[image]

Comment: That is how excel is interpreting that data. Open up the csv file in notepad or TextEdit and see what the actual values are.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @It_is_Chris yeah, I opened it with text editor now and I can see the values as dates. Is there no way to make the csv also display the values as dates?

Comment: That's an Excel question, try asking at [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the cell format in excel

[image: image1]
When the cell format is 'General' it will show just the number 44728.13542

But when you change it to 'date' you will get what you need.
[image]